# Make announcement move from up to down in sharepoint 2013

Tags: web-part, branding, announcements

I put an announcement webpart in my first page but I want the announcement move from up to down and not to be static what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to have dynamic announcement

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2013/05/adding-scrolling-list-of-messages-to.html

Comment: is it possible for this, without usng  content query web part? i dont have publishing feature enable din my site collecand subsite level.